# If $G$ is generated by $n$ elements and $H$ is generated by $m$ elements, then show that $G\times H$ is generated by $m+n$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $G$ is generated by $n$ elements and $H$ is generated by $m$ elements, then show that $G\times H$ is generated by $m+n$ elements.

But online I keep seeing that the order of a direct product is $m$ multiplied by $n$, not the sum... So I'm confused. Is this related to order?

Comment: The order has nothing to do with the number of generators. For an easy example, $\mathbb{Z}_k$ has order $k$ but is generated by only one element.

Comment: @kigen It has "$\varphi(k)$ generators", for some authors.

Comment: Oh, you are correct...I can't figure out how to show that...I could simply say since the direct product is defined component-wise then it implies the whole product is generated by the sum of generators

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, $\mathbb{Z}_k$ can have more than one generator, but one element suffices to generate it. That's usually what we mean when we say "$G$ is generated by $n$ elements": there are $n$ distinct elements of $G$ so that every element of $G$ is a finite product of these elements, not that each of these $n$ elements independently generate $G$.

Comment: @kigen I know, I was just trying to convey that the meanings, as you note, vary.

Comment: ^thanks so much, I spent a hour wondering why there were different definitions, but they weren't different. Any clues on how to prove it though?

Comment: @cakey You can try listing the generators directly. If $g_1,\ldots, g_n$ generate $G$ and $h_1,\ldots, h_m$ generate $H$, can you use this to write down generators for $G\times H$? And if you can, can you show that no smaller set can generate $G\times H$?

Comment: Well that would make [(g1,g2,..,gm),(h1,h2...,hm)] and can I say that by just observation that the direct product is m+n? And I'm not sure how to show that ot is the smallest. How do you generally show that a sum is the smallest you can get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks you to prove that $K=G\times H$ can be generated by $m+n$ elements, where $G$ is generated by $m$ elements and $H$ is generated by $n$ elements.

**Hint:** The elements of $G$ with the elements of $H$ generate $K=G\times H$.

So, the generators of $G$ combined with the generators of $H$ generate $K$, or rather $\{(g, 1);\:g\text{ is a generator for $G$}\}\cup\{(h, 1);\:h\text{ is a generator for $H$}\}$ generate $K=G\times H$.

Note that "$m+n$" is not minimal. For example, if $G$ is cyclic of order three, $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $H$ is cyclic of order two, $H\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, them $K=G\times H$ is cyclic of order six. So $m+n=2$ but $K$ can be generated by only one element.

Comment: So the generator for H isn't (1,h)? For a direct product, I remember the 1st is all possible permutations for G and the second is all possible permutations for H,  is that wrong to think of? I like the Z notation it helps me see what you said in the last part.

Comment: Except, for the last example, how come m+n=2? Is it because for cyclic groups, they only have one generator each?

Comment: is it because Z2 and Z3 have the same generator? 1 bar?

Comment: $1\in\mathbb Z_2$ is not the same as $1\in\mathbb Z_3$, but both are generators of the respective groups, so $n=1$ and $m=1$. The general construction gives you $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$ as a generating set of $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_3$ in this case, since $0$ is the additive neutral element. But there is a smaller generating set: $\{(1,1)\}$, since $(1,0)=3(1,1)$ and $(0,1)=4(1,1)$.

Comment: So is the notion that for direct products that they can can m+n or less generators? Since in your example up here you showed that it can have one generators for the Z mod n group.

Comment: Yup, my point was that they can have $m+n$ or fewer generators. the question is simply asking "can you do it with $m+n$". If you feel that you understand the solution to this question now, try the following exercise: Consider $\mathbb{N}$ under addition, $(\mathbb{N}, +)$, where $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain zero. How many elements does it take to generate $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$? (Note: $(\mathbb{N}, +)$ is *not* a group.)

Comment: I would say just N is generated by 1 under addition, so the direct product is generated by 2 elements?

Comment: @cakey Which two?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The elements of $G\times H$ are pairs $(g, h)$ with $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. Let $g_1,\dots,g_n\in G$ generate $G$ and $h_1,\dots,h_m\in H$ generate $H$. Can you find counterparts to the generators of $G$ and $H$ inside $G\times H$?

Comment: Well, if I found counter parts would that mean I must have n+1 G generators and likewise for H?

Comment: Why? What counterparts did you find?

Comment: Sorry,I mean if I use the above notation from the other user,{(g,1) , g is generator for G} U {(h,1),h is generator for H}, then if I can find a bigger m+n it means I must have more generators in G or more generators in H than I actually have. Is this correct? Also why is H (h,1), not (1,h)?

Comment: $(h,1)$ is wrong. You have a generating set $\{(g_1,1_H),\dots,(g_n,1_H),(1_G,h_1),\dots,(1_G,h_m)\}$ of $m+n$ elements, check that every $(g,h)\in G\times H$ is generated by that. I don't understand what you mean by "find a bigger m+n"?

Comment: Okay, that notation looks more understandable to me. Well, once I have that set up I'm a bit lost as to show, I thought it is obvious to say that the total generators must be m+n since  GXH is defined component wise with 2 components...or is that not enough?